# Jquery UI Menu & Resizable - Overlap

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I set the Z-index on menu (100) and on Resizable Div (1) . still the menu is not showing the mouse hover shade ? what i am missing - is it css style ?

```
$( "#menu" ).menu();
$("#menu").find('li').each(function(){
        $(this).css('zIndex','100');
    $(this).find('a').each(function(){
        $(this).css('zIndex','100');
});
});
$('#resize').resizable();

$('#resize').find('div').each(function(){
        $(this).css('zIndex','1');

});
```

here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dekajp/yynPY/3/

Comment: you should set `z-index:100` on the `ul` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `z-index` on the `ul` tag too

**[Update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yynPY/4/)**

Comment: it worked !!! thank you. i think the code should be  $(this).css('z-index','100');  - typo

Comment: Yes, you're right, I did't saw that error, i assume that the script was correct and that's why i set the z-index into the html code..

Comment: Also i realized my original code , was inside a div tag and it did not had the position hence the z-index was overriden to Auto. now all working - thanks